How do I calculate this limit? $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3 + n + 1} - \sqrt{n^2 - n + 2}}$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3 + n + 1} - \sqrt{n^2 - n + 2}}.$$
Not sure what I can do. Would appreciate hints.

$\sqrt[3]{n^3 + n + 1}=n\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3} $ then use Taylor expansion. SImilarly with the other term...

What did you try?

Are you familiar with "multiplying by the conjugate" to eliminate rational powers? In other words, recall the factorization of $a^n-b^n$.

I tried this, but I'm not sure how to factorize $a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}$

You have that backward - you want $a^6-b^6$, and that divides into $a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}$ times a small mess.

You can apply consistently firstly $x^2-y^2$ and then $x^3-y^3$. Or reverse.

Hint: evaluate $A:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[3]{n^3+n+1}-n)$ and $B:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\sqrt{n^2-n+2})$, and your limit is $\frac{1}{A+B}$.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

Hint:
It's  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n\left[\left({1 + \dfrac1{n^2} +
\dfrac1{n^3}}\right)^{1/3} - \left({1 - \dfrac1n + \dfrac2{n^2}}\right)^{1/2}\right]}$$
and $(1+\epsilon)^r\approx1+r\epsilon.$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

$$\sqrt[3]{n^3 + n + 1} - \sqrt{n^2 - n + 2}=\frac{\left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac 2 3}-\left(n^2 - n + 2 \right)^{\frac 2 2}}{\left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac 1 3}+\left(n^2 - n + 2 \right)^{\frac 1 2}}=\\
\frac{\left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac {2\cdot 3}{3}}-\left(n^2 - n + 2 \right)^{\frac {2\cdot3}{2}}}{\left[ \left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac 1 3}+\left(n^2 - n + 2 \right)^{\frac 1 2}\right]\left[ \left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac {4}{3}}+ \left( n^3 + n + 1 \right)^{\frac {2}{3}}  
 \left(n^2 - n + 2 \right) + \left(n^2 - n + 2 \right)^2\right]}$$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Your statements are false. Please review the comments before writing.

I did before. I maintain, and agree with the other voters to close.

Sandwich theorem with
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n-\sqrt{n^2-n+2}}\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+n+1}-\left(n-\frac 12\right)}.$$
The former limit lies completely above the desired limit; to compute just rationalize the denominator and multiply the top and bottom by $\frac 1n$. The latter limit lies completely below the desired limit; to compute just show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt[3]{n^3+n+1}-n)=0$, which follows from using $a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$ and multiplying the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
